# JS Animation to visability:hidden stutters

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function hideContent(){
      document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      }

      function showContent(){
      document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = 'visible';
      }
```

```html
<div class="content" id="content">

    <p class="date">25 mei 2019</p>
    <p class="location">Hennemeeuwis Neerpelt</p>
    <h1>Masquarade Classix </h1>
    <ul class="lineup">
        <li>Nina Kraviz</li>
        <li>Recondite</li>
        <li>Mind Against</li>
        <li>Âme</li>
        <li>Vince Watson</li>
        <li>Kölsch</li>
        <li>Rodriguez Jr. </li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
<div class="clear"></div>

    <a href="#" class="button white">Buy Tickets</a>
    <a onclick="openNav()" href="#" class="button black">More Information</a>

</div>
```

I am animating a div to `visability:hidden` but there is a weird lag/stutter with the buttons within the div, as they disappear asynchronous. Check out hosted on here: http://setup.industries/masquarade/

Also while we are on the topic, can someone point me in the right direction on how to add fade to these animations in vanilla JS?

Thank you!

```
  function hideContent(){
  document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }

  function showContent(){
  document.getElementById('content').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```

Comment: Use `transition: .5s; opacity: 1`, then set opacity to 0.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, that works! Also going to display:none seems to work as well. I guess the stutter has to do with how the DOM renders :hidden? 

Also, do you know how I could add a 1s fade on this opacity change in vanilla JS?